# Save values in a dataframe and replace them in a csv

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, dictionary

so im not quite sure how to formulate the question, as im quite new in pythong and coding in general.
I have a GUI that displays already available information form a csv:

```
def updatetext(self):
    """adds information extracted from database already provided"""


    df_subj = Content.extract_saved_data(self.date)

    self.lineEditFirstDiagnosed.setText(str(df_subj["First_Diagnosed_preop"][0])) \
        if str(df_subj["First_Diagnosed_preop"][0]) != 'nan' else self.lineEditFirstDiagnosed.setText('')
    self.lineEditAdmNeurIndCheck.setText(str(df_subj['Admission_preop'][0])) \
```

works great

now, if i chenge values in the GUI, i want them to be updated in the csv.
I started like this:

```
def onClickedSaveReturn(self):
    """closes GUI and returns to calling (main) GUI"""

    df_general = Clean.get_GeneralData()

    df_subj = {k: '' for k in Content.extract_saved_data(self.date).keys()} # extract empty dictionary
    df_subj['ID'] = General.read_current_subj().id[0]
    df_subj['PID'] = df_general['PID_ORBIS'][0]
    df_subj['Gender'] = df_general['Gender'][0]
    df_subj['Diagnosis_preop'] = df_general['diagnosis'][0]

    df_subj["First_Diagnosed_preop"] = self.lineEditFirstDiagnosed.text()
    df_subj['Admission_preop'] = self.lineEditAdmNeurIndCheck.text()
    df_subj['Dismissal_preop'] = self.DismNeurIndCheckLabel.text()
```

and this is what my boss added now:

```
subj_id = General.read_current_subj().id[0] # reads data from curent_subj (saved in ./tmp)
df = General.import_dataframe('{}.csv'.format(self.date), separator_csv=',')
if df.shape[1] == 1:
    df = General.import_dataframe('{}.csv'.format(self.date), separator_csv=';')

idx2replace = df.index[df['ID'] == subj_id][0]

# TODO: you need to find a way to turn the dictionaryy df_subj into a dataframe and replace the data at
#  the index idxreplace of 'df' with df_subj. Later I would suggest to use line 322 to save everything to the
#  file
df.iloc[idx2replace] = pds.DataFrame([df_subj])
df.to_csv("preoperative.csv", index=False)
# df.to_csv(os.path.join(FILEDIR, "preoperative.csv"), index=False)

self.close()
```

I'm not really sure how to approach this, or to be honest, what to do at all.

Hope someone can help me.

Thank youu

Comment: Hi, following the guidelines you should not ask "how to do my job" but rather focus the question on the problem you have. Anyway here I would recommend you to start with pandas (python's package for tabular data) tutorials. It should give you some basics what for example index in dataframes is, how to work with those data, change it, etc.. If you get to know the terminology, you can build the question better and often there was already someone else, that asked the same.

Comment: Hey, sure you are right. Unfortunately i had no idea how to approach the problem, as im completely new to the world of prgamming. 
So thank you for the hints

Answer (score 0):

You should load the file only once and keep the DF (`self.df` or something). Then display it and every time the user changes a value in the GUI the DF should update and when the user clicks save you should just overwrite the existing file with the current DF in memory.